# Grafana how can I make sure two plots' x-axis aligned perfectly

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have two plots queried from InfluxDB that share the same timestamps.

But as you can see in the pictures that because the y-axis label of the bottom graph takes up more space the two plots misaligned in the timestamp.

I would really like to be able to plot these two sets of data perfectly aligned so I can see how one affects the other.

Can you advice how I can achieve that ? Or being able to make a subplot that is draw two time series plots in one panel, sharing the x-axis would also be great.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest using one panel only, with 2 y-axis. Bit old but probably still similar process: https://grafana.com/blog/2020/03/10/learn-grafana-how-to-use-dual-axis-graphs/

Comment: @dnnshssm . Thanks this is what I am looking for. But this is old version indeed. Now you need to add override properties for the query. Just a bit different in UX.